# How to get Seekbar current background and progress bar color on Android

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I need to retrieve the color of the Seekbar background/progress based on the current theme. How can I do that.
I can get the ColorFilter object by calling

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().getColorFilter()
```

for example but I don't know how to get the color from a ColorFilter
Any idea how I can extract those colors?

Comment: Sorry for asking but why would you want to know the seekbar color?

Comment: I need to create a custom seekbar, but it needs to have the exact same colors as the regular one and my app allows users to select custom themes